# Single Instance VS PerCall in WCF

Tags: wcf, performance, concurrency, instance

There are a lot of posts saying that `SingleInstance` is a bad design. But I think it is the best choice in my situation.
In my service I have to return a list of currently logged-in users (with additional data). This list is identical for all clients. I want to retrieve this list from database every 5 seconds (for example) and return a copy of it to the client, when needed.
If I use `PerCall` instancing mode, I will retrieve this list from database every single time. This list is supposed to contain ~200-500 records, but can grow up to 10 000 in the future. Every record is complex and contains about 10 fields.

So what about performance? Is it better to use "bad design" and get list once or to use "good approach" and get list from database on every call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what about performance? Is it better to use "bad design" and get
>   list once or to use "good approach" and get list from database on
>   every call?

**Performance and good design are NOT mutually exclusive**. The problem with using a single instance is that it can only service a single request at a time. So all other requests are waiting on it to finish doing it's thing.

**Alternatively you could just leverage a [caching layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx)** to hold the results of your query instead of coupling that to your service.

Then your code *might* look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<BigDataRecord> GetBigExpensiveQuery(){

   //Double checked locking pattern is necessary to prevent
   // filling the cache multiple times in a multi-threaded
   // environment
   if(Cache["BigQuery"] == null){
      lock(_bigQueryLock){
         if(Cache["BigQuery"] == null){
            var data = DoBigQuery();
            Cache.AddCacheItem(data, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
         }
      }
   }

   return Cache["BigQuery"];

}
```

Now you can have as many instances as you want all accessing the same Cache.

Comment: You could set ConcurrencyMode to multiple usingInstanceContextMode Single, to serve multiple request at the same instance simultaneously

Comment: @Soulbe - But I'm assuming that he intends to keep the data in-memory. Which means now he has to make sure his service instance is thread safe as well. Why go through all that effort when you can just use `System.Runtime.Caching` which is already thread safe?

Comment: In fact I was thinking to use single instance with multiple concurrency mode :S But your solution will make my work much easier. Things I didn't get: all instances will share the same cache? how can I update cached values from database by timer?

Comment: @ChruS - You don't have to. Just set the cache value to have an absolute timeout of 5 seconds from now. That way the first person to request the values after 5 seconds populates the cache, and any subsequent calls will pull the cached value. This has the advantage of not hitting the database when nobody is asking for data.